# Возможно ли отправить сообщение в Viber по номеру телефоне, а не по id подписки?

Tags: rest, viber

Начал работать с [Viber REST Api](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/). Получил Публичный аккаунт и ключ. Но в методе по отправке сообщения, есть поле `reciever` что должно содержать ID подписанного пользователя. Реально ли сделать так, чтобы отправляло на номер телефона,  а не по id. Или же подписать юзера на публичный аккаунт? Каким образом ему можно отправить сообщение, имея только его телефон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак для Публичного аккаунта. Отправлять сообщения по номеру телефона могут только сервисные рассылки https://www.viber.com/viber-for-business/

Comment: а после оплаты данного сервиса, viber предоставить api?

Comment: @SergShapoval нужно подать заявку на их сайте. Главный критерий — больше 60 тис. сообщений отправлять в месяц

Comment: уже подал. они предоставят потом апи для взаимодействия?

Comment: @SergShapoval а как же, после одобрения

Comment: спасибо большое за информацию